# Data cannot be retrieved - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've a scenario where I'm fetching data from c# and want to show it on my cshtml view. Now the problem is although my Angular file (EditSingleRecord.js) is retrieving the list . I can't fetch it in my cshtml(EditSingleRecord.cshtml).

```js
/// <reference path="C:\Users\Deepak\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EBazar\EBazar\Scripts/angular-resource.min.js" />

(function() {
  //Create a Module 
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', []); // Will use ['ng-Route'] when we will implement routing
  //Create a Controller
  app.controller('MYController', function($scope, $http) { // here $scope is used for share data between view and controller



    $scope.FetchTblName = function() {
      $http({
        url: '/Admin/FetchTableName',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
        }
      }).success(function(data) {

        $scope.TempName = data
        $scope.EditForTable();


        if ($scope.TempName == 'ContactTbl') {
          $('#ContactTbl').show();
          $('#CourseTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
          $('#InternTbl').hide();
          $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        } else if ($scope.TempName == 'CourseTbl') {
          $('#ContactTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseTbl').show();
          $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
          $('#InternTbl').hide();
          $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        } else if ($scope.TempName == 'CourseDescTbl') {
          $('#ContactTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseDescTbl').show();
          $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
          $('#InternTbl').hide();
          $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        } else if ($scope.TempName == 'CourseSubDesc') {
          $('#ContactTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseSubDescTbl').show();
          $('#InternTbl').hide();
          $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        } else if ($scope.TempName == 'InternTbl') {
          $('#ContactTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
          $('#InternTbl').show();
          $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        } else if ($scope.TempName == 'LocationTbl') {
          $('#ContactTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
          $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
          $('#InternTbl').hide();
          $('#LocationTbl').show();
        }

      });


    };


    $scope.EditForTable = function() {
      var Data = $.param({});
      var MyEditTblList = [];

      $http({
        url: '/Admin/FetchDataForEdit',
        method: 'POST',
        data: Data,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
        }
      }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.MyEditTblList = data;
      }).error(function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    }

  })

})();
```

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MYController">

  <div class="container">

    <h2>{{TempName}} Details</h2>

    <div class="table table-responsive">
      <table id="LocationTbl" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="margin:0px 5px; width:800px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              S. No.
            </td>
            <td>
              Loc ID
            </td>
            <td>
              Location Name
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>


        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in MyEditTblList">
            <td>
              {{$index+1}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{row.ID}}
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="row.LocName" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
```

The Problem is although MyEditTblList is fetching records but I cannot see records on my cshtml. Please HELP!!

Comment: Is TempName displaying? And, what data are you getting over line ` $scope.MyEditTblList = data;` ?

Comment: Yeah TempName is giving me expected name and the later line  is fetching my records correctly.

Comment: I suspect in the MyEditTblList object. Your assignment should be like this :  `$scope.MyEditTblList = data.data;`. For good naming, you can rename resolving response `data` as `response` and then do like this `$scope.MyEditTblList = response.data;`

Comment: I don't think so. $scope.MyEditTblList = data is fetching records correctly. My list is filled and in my browser I can see the result. Also I've used $scope.MyEditTblList = data at many other places in my project all of them are executing correctly.

Comment: Sorry, you are using `success` resolver. I thought it as `then` resolver

Comment: You can have  `$scope.MyEditTblList = [];` rather than  `var MyEditTblList = [];` and declare outside function `EditForTable` scope

Comment: It didn't make any difference. Still no data.

Comment: What version of angularjs u using ? in latest version `success` callback is deprecated. Use `then` instead

Comment: It seems that the result you are storing in MyEditTblList is a string and you need to parse it before assigning it to MyEditTblList.

Comment: Did you verify that you are getting data through Developer Tools > Network in your browser?

Comment: @rahul using Angularjs 1

Comment: @Ephraim yes. And I'm getting the expected result there.